# How to use article name on the url on Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to use article name on the url on Yii2 which is like http://example.com/article?id=1, just replace id=1 to article_name, like  http://example.com/article/article_name or is it.

This is my controller code-

```
$model = Articles::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();
```

View-

```
<?= Html::a('<b>Read more ...</b>', ['article-details','id' => $model->id], ['target'=>'_blank']) ?>
```

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use yii2 sluggable behavior [Refer this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-sluggable-behavior--cms-23222).
There are few steps.
 You must add the following urlManager rule :

```
'article/<slug>' => 'article/view',
```

You should build  url in your view files like this :

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['article/view', 'slug'=>$model->title])
```

or

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['article/'.$model->title]);
```

And in your action

```
public function actionArticle($slug){
$model = Articles::find()->where(["title"=>$slug])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();
//and other code
}
```

Also your article titles must be valid for url.You can do it easly by trimming whitespaces and so on But also you can add url some identification propery. or add column stored unique slugs for  every article

Answer (score 0):

You have two way

one change the related action in the controller changing id with name in the related function declaration

or declare a new action with the name as parameter

```
public function findModelName($article_name)
{
    $model = Article::findOne(['name'=> $article_name]);
     ........ your related code 

}
```

you can find the model by name this way

```
Article::findOne(['name'=> $article_name]);
```

Comment: Hi **scaisEdge**  Finally set this URL http://example.com/article-details/article name but after click this url showing  Page not found.

Comment: Check if you have the proper controller  `ArticleDetailsController`  and the the subdir `article-details` in your view directory and the article related view in subdir